# Firebase Authen with Facebook error need to upgrade

Tags: facebook, firebase, upgrade, firebase-authentication

Error is showing in image below :

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HV0qV.png

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the Firebase 2.x SDK on a project that will only allow using the newer SDK. The solution is to use the newer SDK. This has been covered quite a few times before. If you search for the error message, you'll find those.

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution on FireBase guides page https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web

Answer (score 1):

The solution is upgraded version of Firebase:
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web